# malloc(): memory corruption in try block

Tags: c++, malloc, memory-corruption

I have a stack class that I am running test cases on and I've run into a problem when trying to pop an empty stack. The source file code involved:

```
stack::stack(int)
{
    _tos = -1;
    _capacity = 8;
    _arr = new int[_capacity];
}

void stack::push(const TYPE x)
{
    if(_tos == _capacity - 1)
    {
        int new_arr[_capacity * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < _capacity; i++)
            new_arr[i] = _arr[i];
        _arr = new_arr
    }
    _arr[++_tos] = x;
}

void stack::pop()
{
    if(stack::empty())
        throw EmptyStackException();
    _tos--;
}

bool stack::empty()
{
    if(_tos == -1)  //_tos == -1 when the stack is empty
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The test case code I'm using(found at the very end of main()):

```
try {
    s.pop();
} catch ( EmptyStackException e ){
    cout << "exception caught \n";
}
```

Prior to this my tests pushed 10000 values to the stack and then removed all of them without issue so there is no problem with my pop() in general.

My error(condensed):

```
*** Error in `./stackTest2': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000006d2ca0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7cbac)[0x7f7b21805bac]
...
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 23070058                           
...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Initially I thought that the problem had nothing to do with the try block but if I comment it out the error goes away so it must be triggering it to happen in some way.

**Edit: Added more code for context**
It is unlikely that the try block is the cause of the problem but like a comment said it is probably triggering it
I also cannot change the fact that the stack is built on an array that is updated once it is full

Comment: Please have a [mcve]. Now, what is `_tos`? Let me guess, is it a `size_t`? >>> A question with a [mcve] should not make answerers "guess" to get your problem.

Comment: (summary about MCVE: Instead of "throwing away" parts of source code that is unrelated to the problem, just remove them from the logic such that the program is still complete (**compilable**))

Comment: It's likely that the memory corruption is not caused by the exception, but is detected during the exception processing.

Comment: @user202729 I added more code from the class source file for context. _tos is the index of the top of the stack.

Comment: [mcve] means compilable by itself without additional header file/include/etc. Obviously in this case the `push` function is unrelated, you can remove it from the MCVE. Please read the MCVE help page again and follow that carefully.

Comment: @Sean -- *Prior to this my tests pushed 10000 values to the stack and then removed all of them without issue so there is no problem with my pop() in general.* -- Please don't think that just because some of your code "runs ok" means that the code is ok.  C++ doesn't work that way -- if you have a memory corruption issue, the memory could have been corrupted in the code you believe has no issues.  That's why you should always post a [mcve].

Comment: @Sean `int new_arr[_capacity * 2];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must be declared using a constant expression, not a run-time value.  If you had used standard C++ such as `std::vector` instead of that syntax, the mistake pointed out by the answer given by `sth` would not have occurred.  But this also brings up the point of ruling out code just because you believed it "worked".

Comment: Make it easier on people who want to help. Post a [MCVE], all in one piece. (No separate header files, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor you allocate a new array for `_arr`. In `push()`, if you want to increase the capacity, you copy the elements to an array **on the stack** and save a pointer to that array in `_arr`. This is not safe since the array will go out of scope at the end of the `if` block in that function, leaving a dangling pointer in `_arr`.

Writing to that dangling pointer or trying to `delete[]` it can easily lead to memory corruption.

Comment: Hey, but according to the OP, it worked when 1000 items were pushed ;-)

Comment: Also, `int new_arr[_capacity * 2];` that line of code isn't valid C++, as it uses VLA's.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I'll try going at this a different way

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you I didn't catch that, also I'm just as surprised as you are that the 1000 items being pushed worked to be honest!

Comment: Never underestimate Undefined Behaviour's ability to smurf with your head.

Comment: As long as you only call push() and no other functions that use the stack for other purposes, everything could stay in place long enough to not immediately cause problems.